# Java Pattern regex

Tags: java, regex

When I try:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,.s;:{}/[]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
```

my program bugs out. Why doesn't it like this?

Comment: You mean by crash that it is throwing an exception ? What does that exception say ?

Comment: Maybe you are missing an import ?

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression won't compile because in Java you need to escape square brackets `[`, `]` when you use them inside character classes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,.s;:{}/\\[\\]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
                                      ^^^^^^
```

The double escape `\\` is needed because slashes `\` are used in Java strings to escape special sequences like `\n`, `\r` ... etc

Now how do we include a literal slash in a Java string when we need one if it is used to escape stuff ?

We escape it using it self thus typing it twice `\\`.

Why do we need to escape `[` and `]` inside character classes ?

Because [Java supports character class subtraction, intersection and union](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), for example:

```
[a-d[m-p]]  a through d, or m through p: [a-dm-p] (union)
[a-z&&[def]]    d, e, or f (intersection)
[a-z&&[^bc]]    a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```

<sup>Examples are taken from the documentation.</sup>

Comment: Why the double escape?

Comment: @AprilRandolph Because the backslash needs to be escaped too!

Comment: @AprilRandolph I have edited my answer to cover your comment.

Comment: @AprilRandolph If this question solves your problem then you should accept it by clicking the tick mark to the left :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters such as [, ], +, (, ) etc. I'm not 100% sure but you might be able to use \Q and \E to tell the regex to treat the special chars as literals.

Eg:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\Q,.s;:{}/[]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=\\E]");
```

See the **Quotation** section in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Also since you are using quotation `[\\Q\\[\\]\\E]` escaping `[` and `]` is incorrect because it will make `\, [, \, ]` literals in character class and OP don't want to include \ in this class.

Comment: Hmm... it seems I copy / pasted a regex from another answer instead of the the regex from the original question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,.s;:{}/\\[\\]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
```

**You need to escape `[` and `]`**

OR this will also work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[],.s;:{}/\\[<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
```

With only `[` needs to be escaped.

**`]` can avoid escaping if it is at first position inside character class.**

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you have to skip the special characters ...
In order to do that I will suggest you to use the `Pattern.quote` method (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as a reference).

```
String s = Pattern.quote("[,.s;:{}/[]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s);
```